# Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Data Flow tutorials

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am very new to Spring Cloud Data Flow and have enough experience with Spring Batch. Can anybody share some tutorials link for Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Data Flow?

I am looking to orchestrate to run Job1, Job2 and Job3 in sequence, in some cases its a part of same Jar and in some case those are independent jars. I am also looking for Job restart and should be able to see all details about Job.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody share some tutorials link for Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Here are some links to get started:

- [Spring Batch getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)
- [SCDF getting started guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/getting-started/)
- [SCDF local installation guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/)
- [SCDF batch developer guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/batch/)
- [SCDF composed task sample](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/batch/data-flow-composed-task/)